# Multiple scale images before overlay it - FFMPEG

Tags: image, ffmpeg, overlay

I'm using ffmpeg library to develop android mobile application that can overlay images, draw texts and merge audio to video file then display it

I'm using this command to overlay two images into .avi video

```
   ffmpeg -i inputvid  -i photoOne.png  -i photoTwo.png  -filter_complex [1:v]scale=320:320[ovrl],[0:v][ovrl] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)' 
,overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'" outvid
```

This command Scale the first  images only to 320:320, but i want to scale the second image to 400:400 and i don't know how to specify a scale for the second photo.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for the development of software. For issues using software like `ffmpeg`, try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks bro, but  i'm using ffmpeg to make android app that can overlay images into video 

i'm sorry i forget to mention that
i edit the question is that ok?

Comment: Eh, not really. The intended use of the resulting image isn't really relevant. I might work as a stock broker saving money to build a house, but I wouldn't go to a construction company to ask about stock investment strategies.

Comment: OH i got it, sorry for wrong usage 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
ffmpeg -i inputvid  -i photoOne.png  -i photoTwo.png  -filter_complex \
        "[1:v]scale=320:320[ovr1]; [2:v]scale=400:400[ovr2]; \
         [0:v][ovr1]overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'[int]; \
         [int]ovr2]overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,10)'[out]" \
       -map "[out]" outvid
```

Noe that since your ovelay co-ordinates are the same. The 2nd image will cover up the first image in the result.

Comment: Thanks man it's works fine you saved me 
i know that i will change the time later , but did you know how to set the time in MilliSecond not in second?
Thanks

Comment: Divide by thousand, so 3804 milliseconds is `3.804`

Comment: [NULL @ 0xf09bce00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[2:v]scale=460:800[ovr2]'
[2:v]scale=460:800[ovr2]: Invalid argument

@Gyan